# Isotope - masonry jquery filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Can someone please help me to understand what Am I doing wrong ? 
I am using the isotope jquery plugin , all works ok, except filtering ..

I reproduced the problem here --> http://jsfiddle.net/AxCCT/

this looks pretty straight forward , I am obviously missing the obvious here .

I have followed the instructions here http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Progress!](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/AxCCT/16/)

I changed a lot of stuff and it is sort of working now. It sorts and then immediately snaps back (might be a jsFiddle thing? Try loading this into your page and see what happens)

I'm doing an Isotope project right now at the moment and I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initialize isotope
});
```

I tried to use that in the Fiddle but it didn't like it for some reason.

**Edit:** working solution below, thanks to @jaychapani for pointing out the HTML error.

Comment: That's it! That's what I get for not looking at the HTML. You should use `<a href="javascript:;"` to avoid viewport jumping. See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/AxCCT/18/)

Comment: Great , thanks , Actually the original problem started because I had jQuery 1.6.4 on my page . It seem to be working only with 1.7.1 and up. none the less , you pointed me in the right direction. thanks again !